# Problem with pgfplots and histograms

Tags: pgfplots

I just played with @Jakes pgfplots binomial examples from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198575/4011, however the histogram seems to be shifted to the left or to the right depending on the whole plot (look for example at the k=50 value below). Any idea what's wrong here? Might it be because of numerical errors from pgfplots? How to fix it?

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  declare
  function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=
    (\k <= \n)*\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k) 
    ;}%
  ]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=center,%
    ymax=0.25,%
    ymin=0,%
    xmax=60,%
    samples at={0,1,...,50},%
    yticklabel style={%
      /pgf/number format/fixed,%
      /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,%
      /pgf/number format/precision=1,%
      /pgf/number format/use comma },%
    ybar=0pt,bar width=0.5,%
    xlabel=$k$,%
    ylabel=$B_{n,p}(k)$, minor x tick num=0, ymajorgrids,
    width=15cm, height=6cm]
    \addplot [fill=gray!50, fill opacity=0.5]
    {binom(x,50,0.9)};%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  declare
  function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=
    (\k <= \n)*\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k) 
    ;}%
  ]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=center,%
    ymax=0.25,%
    ymin=0,%
    xmax=60,%
    samples at={0,1,...,50},%
    yticklabel style={%
      /pgf/number format/fixed,%
      /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,%
      /pgf/number format/precision=1,%
      /pgf/number format/use comma },%
    ybar=0pt,bar width=0.5,%
    xlabel=$k$,%
    ylabel=$B_{n,p}(k)$, minor x tick num=0, ymajorgrids,
    width=15cm, height=6cm]
    \addplot [fill=black, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,50,0.7)};%
    \addplot [fill=gray!50, fill opacity=0.5]
    {binom(x,50,0.9)};%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  declare
  function={binom(\k,\n,\p)=
    (\k <= \n)*\n!/(\k!*(\n-\k)!)*\p^\k*(1-\p)^(\n-\k) 
    ;}%
  ]
  \begin{axis}[%
    axis lines=center,%
    ymax=0.25,%
    ymin=0,%
    xmax=60,%
    samples at={0,1,...,50},%
    yticklabel style={%
      /pgf/number format/fixed,%
      /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,%
      /pgf/number format/precision=1,%
      /pgf/number format/use comma },%
    ybar=0pt,bar width=0.5,%
    xlabel=$k$,%
    ylabel=$B_{n,p}(k)$, minor x tick num=0, ymajorgrids,
    width=15cm, height=6cm]

    \addplot [fill=gray!50, fill opacity=0.5]
    {binom(x,50,0.9)};%
    \addplot [fill=black, fill opacity=0.5] {binom(x,50,0.7)};%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

[image: Diagram 3]

Comment: When you're plotting more than one series using the `bar` style, PGFPlots offsets the series so they don't overlap. If you don't want that, set `bar shift=0pt`.

Comment: @Jake, please convert your comment to answer.

Comment: @Jake Thanks that works. But then I don't really understand the syntax, the manual says `/pgfplots/ybar={<shift for multiple plots>}` and `ybar` is set to zero. Furthermore the manual says that `bar shift` is initially zero. Perhaps you can also explain this if you turn your commaent to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: When using `ybar` in the `axis` options, PGFPlots will shift the different series to avoid overlapping bars. If you want the bars not to be shifted, set `bar shift=0pt`.

---

**`ybar` in the `axis` options, single series**

If you use the `ybar` key in the `axis` options and plot just a single series, you'll get bars centered over the specified x positions:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {x};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

---

**`ybar` in the `axis` options, two series**

If you add another series, PGFPlots will offset the first series to the left and the second series to the right, so the bars don't overlap. By default, there's a `2pt`  gap between bars with the same x-coordinate:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {x};
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {5-x};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

---

**`ybar=0pt` in the `axis` options, two series**

You can adjust the width of the gap between the series by using the optional argument to the `ybar` style in the `axis` options. If you set `ybar=0pt`, the bars will be flush with each other:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {x};
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {5-x};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

---

**`ybar, bar shift=0pt` in the `axis` options, two series**

If you don't want the bars to be shifted in different directions, you can set `bar shift=0pt`. That way, bars with the same x-coordinate will be drawn in the same location, leading to overlapping bars:

```
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar shift=0pt,
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {x};
    \addplot +[samples at={1,...,5}] {5-x};
\end{axis}
```

[image]

In the PGFPlots manual, it says that `bar shift` "configures a shift for `xbar` and `ybar`", and that the default value for this style is `0pt`. Why then do you get different results when including or omitting `bar shift=0pt`? That's because calling `ybar` in the `axis` options overwrites the default value for `bar shift` and replaces it with a mathematical expression:

```
/pgf/bar shift={%
        % total width = n*w + (n-1)*skip
        % -> subtract half for centering
        -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype*\pgfplotbarwidth + (\numplotsofactualtype-1)*(#1))  + 
        % the '0.5*w' is for centering
        (.5+\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)}
```

That expression leads to the shift we saw in examples 2 and 3. The `#1` parameter is the gap between the bars (`2pt` by default).

---

**`ybar` in the `\addplot` options, `bar shift=5pt` in the `axis` options, two series**

You can check that the default value for `bar shift` is indeed, as the manual says, `0pt`, by moving the `ybar` key from the `axis` options to the `\addplot` options and setting a different value for `bar shift` in the `axis` options. Now all the bars are shifted to the right by `5pt`:

```
\begin{axis}[
    bar shift=5pt,
    ymin=0
]
    \addplot +[ybar, mark=none, fill=blue!30!white, samples at={1,...,5}] {x};
    \addplot +[ybar, mark=none, fill=red!30!white, samples at={1,...,5}] {5-x};
\end{axis}
```

[image]